# Querying for admins (hosts) of a Facebook event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to determine whether or not a user of my app is an admin (or host as it's now called) for a specific Facebook event. I see that it's possible to determine who created an event but I can't figure our how to determine the additional admins? Querying the event would be fine with me as would querying the user. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to determine this with the current table definitions.  You could try to modify data on the event that only an admin can modify.  If you don't mind doing that, then you can use the user's access token to try to modify the event and see if you're successful or not. And that would tell you if the current user is an admin of the event or not.